# Variable as a function

Tags: javascript

I cannot achieve a task of passing a variable into a function.

So first line of code is:

```
window.action1(news);
```

After it has been executed I would like use "news" as a function:

```
window.action1 = function (action2) {
  window.action2(); // which supposed to be news instead of action2
}
```

Comment: Just call `action2` directly, with `action2()`. Or do you pass the name of the function only, instead of a function itself? In this case, don't. )

Answer (score 2):

If you pass a function name as a string, you would be calling:

```
window[action2](); // <-- notice the use of square bracket notation, since "action2" is just a variable string
```

if instead you are passing the function directly, just call it:

```
action2();
```